# Unity3D, Imported package's code not showing in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have imported standard [unitypackage](https://github.com/heroiclabs/nakama-unity/releases) file to my Unity3D project which has its own C# code. Then I open my Visual Studio Community Edition in order to use its code as namespace and I get this:

[image: Not loading]

It doesn't even showing in Solution of this project:

[image: No folder]

There is no `Nakama` folder where these scripts are being located.

Is there any way to recreate project solution?

I'm using **Visual Studio Community Edition 2015 14.0.25**

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 No this unitypackage has only CS files

Comment: hmmm.you couldn't add ur project to ur solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First of all, you should use Visual Studio 2017 (is not mandatory)
2. Then add your project to your solution.
3. Then add a reference to your
           added project.

if you can successfully reference to your project
        only then you can use it.

Comment: My Unity3D can see this namespace and starts game without any problem. However, VisualStudio itself does not updating its own solution.

Comment: give me a pic of ur Solution Explorer

Answer (score 12):

I solved the problem by :

- Adding Embedded packages in Unity settings
- Re-generate project files

Unity 2019.3.15f1
[image]

Noticed that my files was in the `Packages` folder.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, it save me a lot of headaches.

Comment: This helped me. Note that it also works for using Unity packages from Git URLs and OpenUPM.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add your existing project like this one? 
[image]

Comment: Unity3D already created to my solution and project and it uses `Assets` folder. However, `Nakama` folder does not appear after adding it into `Assets`